# Hide button when counter is greater than 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicks = 0;
    $(".next-button").click(function() {
        clicks++;
        $('.figure').html(clicks);
    });
    console.log(clicks);

    if (clicks == 2) {
        $('.next-button').click(function() {

            var nextTab = $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab.current').next();


            $('ul.tabs div.orange-tab').removeClass('current');
            $('div.tab-content').removeClass('current');

            nextTab.addClass('current');
            $('div[id=' + nextTab.attr('data-tab') + ']').addClass('current');


        });
    } else {
        //function to hide the button
    }

});
```

Hi, I have this function and I want when I'm clicking the button to increase the counter and if is greater than 2 for example to hide the button..

```
<div id="next-button" class="text-center"> 
     button id="next_button" name="next_button" class="next-button">Next</button> 
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#next-button').hide()` also id's must be unique and you forgot a `<` at the button

Comment: Your `if (clicks == 2)` should be inside the `$(".next-button").click(function()`

Comment: chnage the condition like if (clicks <= 2) { // } else { }

Comment: `$(".next-button")` means element with CLASS next-button and I see you use the ID in your button `<div id="next-button" class="text-center">` you have to check your jquery selectors and change it to `$("#next-button")`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var clicks = 0; 
     $(".next-button").click(function(){ 
         clicks = clicks+1; 
         $('.figure').html(clicks);
         if(clicks>2){
              $(this).hide();
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Works for me!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        var clicks = 0;
    $(".next-button").click(function() {
    alert('hello');
        clicks++;
        alert(clicks);
        //$('.figure').html(clicks);
        if(clicks==2)
        {

            $("#hide_button").hide();
        }
    });
});
</script>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div id="next-button" class="text-center"> 
    <button id="next_button" name="next_button" class="next-button">Next</button> 
    <button id="hide_button" name="next_button" class="next-button">Hide Me</button> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```